# Notion of maximal atlases in differential geometry

Tags: differential-geometry, manifolds, smooth-manifolds

I'm following a course on differential geometry and from some background I've gotten used to the fact that a topological manifold $M$ is called a smooth/differentiable manifold if we can equip $M$ with some smooth atlas $\mathcal{A}$, then the pair $(M, \mathcal{A})$ is called a differentiable manifold.

Now reading Lee's book I've found out that we actually require $\mathcal{A}$ to be something called maximal. He first states that

> Our plan is to define a “smooth structure” on $M$ by giving a smooth atlas, and to
> define a function $f : M \to \Bbb R$ to be smooth if and only if $f \circ \varphi^{-1}$ is smooth in the sense of ordinary calculus for each coordinate chart $(U, \varphi)$ in the atlas. There is one minor technical problem with this approach: in general, there will be many possible atlases that give the “same” smooth structure, in that they all determine the same collection of smooth functions on $M$.

Then he goes on to state that

> However, it is more straightforward to make the following definition: a smooth atlas $\mathcal{A}$ on $M$ is maximal if it is not properly contained in any larger smooth atlas. This just means that any chart that is smoothly compatible with every chart in $\mathcal{A}$ is already in $\mathcal{A}$.

The lecturer in the course I'm taking says that in practice we only need to consider some atlas $\mathcal{A}$ for $M$ instead of the maximal one which is causing my confusion. Why is this true?

Lee also  gives the proposition $1.17$ which states that

> Let $M$ be a topological manifold, then every smooth atlas $\mathcal{A}$ for $M$ is contained in a unique maximal smooth atlas, called the smooth structure determined by $\mathcal{A}.$

and presumably this is the reason why we can consider some arbitary atlas $\mathcal{A}$ instead of the maximal one?

Why does this imply that we don't need to consider the maximal one? I don't think it's obvious.

Comment: Cf., e.g., https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1556285/manifold-and-maximal-atlas

Comment: @TravisWillse This doesn't address the specific question I was asking.

Comment: @Jasper I know, which is why I didn't mark this post as a duplicate of that one; it's just related enough that the comments there might give some intuition for what's going on w.r.t. your question. See also https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/43187/why-maximal-atlas and perhaps https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2930261/two-atlases-are-compatible-if-and-only-if-their-associated-maximal-atlases-are-e

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A [*smooth manifold structure*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Smooth_structure) on a [topological manifold](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_manifold) $M$ is a choice of maximal [atlas](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Manifold#Atlases) for $M$.

Each atlas $\mathcal{A}$ is contained in a unique maximal atlas consisting of the charts on $M$ that are compatible with $\mathcal{A}$. So it is clear that specifying any atlas automatically determines a unique choice of maximal atlas, hence a smooth manifold structure.

Two atlases $\mathcal{A}_1$ and $\mathcal{A}_2$ are said to be *equivalent* if $\mathcal{A}_1\cup\mathcal{A}_2$ is itself an atlas. This defines an equivalence relation. Each equivalence class contains a unique maximal atlas, and therefore defines a smooth manifold structure.

So to define a smooth manifold structure on $M$, you can either specify a maximal atlas directly, or specify an equivalence class of atlases, or just any atlas.

**Reference:** Lee, J.M., *Manifolds and Differential Geometry* (Indian Edition),  Amer. Math. Soc., 2009

Comment: If I understood you correctly the idea is that we can work with any atlas $\mathcal{A}$ and all the properties we get for that specific atlas will also be available in the maximal atlas $\overline{\mathcal{A}}$ _determined_ by $\mathcal{A}$. So in a sense for any atlas we're always guaranteed a _unique_ maximal atlas which imposes the differentiable/smooth structure on $M$?

Comment: @Jasper Yes, that's right. Ultimately, if you have a topological manifold, the question is: Which maximal atlas are we using in order to turn this into a smooth manifold? Specifying any atlas will answer this question automatically. By the way, I should point out since you are a new user that if an answer adequately resolves your question, then please consider accepting it by clicking the tick under the no. of votes :)

Comment: Thanks! This was bugging me for a while. I had the feeling that I would somehow need to find a _maximal atlas_ everytime I did some work on a manifold with some chosen atlas. I suppose that going up a level of abstraction did resolve my worries this time.

Comment: @Jasper I had exactly the same issue as an undergrad when learning about smooth manifolds for the first time. Having to explicitly find a maximal atlas each time would probably be a bit of a nightmare; that it is not necessary is something that I don't think is communicated very clearly in literature for beginners